# How to parallelize/optimize for loops in a Rank Transform of an image?

Tags: c++, for-loop, image-processing, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to speed up the rank transform of an image using

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

The rank transform is actually similar to a filter operation and I implemented it using nested for loops. The performance of the rank transform of a 1200x1200 image is unchanged and takes about 9.68 s for various #pragma operators.

I tested several configurations from https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/.

<s>The pragma operator in the code sample below has no effect. It marks the part that should be parallelized.
Any ideas how to apply the #pragma operators correctly to have an effect?</s>

System:
Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2019 - Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC),
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// cv::Mat class is used

Mat rank_transform(Mat image, int windowsize)
{
    // input:  CV_8UC1 Mat, padded image with zeros ( borderwidth of padding -> int halfWindow = windowSize/2; )
    // output: CV_8UC1 Mat, unpadded rank transformed image
    // 
    // TO DO: add try..catch modulo 2 of windows size and add one onto the window size when number is even

    int halfWindow = windowsize / 2;

    // iterate over the padded image
    int rows = image.rows;
    int cols = image.cols;

    // only return the true parts of the image without padded values, returned image
    Mat rankImage = Mat(image.rows - 2 * halfWindow, image.cols - 2 * halfWindow, CV_8UC1);
    
    // center pixel position (v, u) starts at half window size 
    // and iterates over all rows as long as row < (totalRows - halfWindow)
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int v = halfWindow; v < rows - halfWindow; v++)
        {
            for (int u = halfWindow; u < cols - halfWindow; u++)
            {
                // initialize rank score
                int score = 0;
                // iterate through the neighboring pixels of a window
                for (int vWin = -halfWindow; vWin <= halfWindow; vWin++)
                {
                    for (int uWin = -halfWindow; uWin <= halfWindow; uWin++)
                    {
                        // if neighbor has a higher intensity than the center pixel, access (row, column)
                        if (image.at<uchar>(v + vWin, u + uWin) > image.at<uchar>(v, u))
                            score++;
                    }
                }
                // access (row, column), write score
                rankImage.at<uchar>(v - halfWindow, u - halfWindow) = score;
            }
        }
    return rankImage;
}
```

Update: After adjusting my Settings in Visual Studio 2019, the code and performing a system restart, I get for a 8UC1 1214x1214 Mat and a window size of 15x15 an elapsed time of 2.65707 s.

Any suggestions for further improvement?

Comment: How to you build your program (flags)? What is your compiler? What is the target OS and the target processor? Please add the informations in the question. Note that the `{` after the `#pragma omp parallel for` is not valid AFAIK.

Comment: Yep, I changed it to #pragma omp parallel { }, which allows the use of brackets according to the documentation.

Comment: If you do that, then the work is not split amongst the threads.  You have to remove the `{` and stick to `parallel for` so that the image is split across the threads,

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a `#pragma omp for` inside the parallel region, just before the first for. Do not forget to provide the compilation flags (which are one of the most important parameter)

Comment: Most probably you forgot to turn on openmp compiler flag (Property Page C++/Language/OpenMP support should be Yes(/openmp)).
As suggested use `#pragma omp parallel for` and remove `{` after it. Note that the web page you mentioned use openMP 4.5 standard, while MSVC is openMP 2.0 compilant only. For more details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=msvc-160

Comment: p.s: @Jerome and Michael you have already answered the question. Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: To optimize the code a minimal working example (e.g. implementation of `Mat` class) is necessary. For me 9.6 s seems to be too long for processing an 1200x1200 image on i7-7700K.

Comment: It is the opencv mat class.